# Command-line Progress bar with occupied indicator

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

I have a program processing a large, lengthy job. I know the size of the task up front so I display a progress bar. 
Yet the individual sub-tasks can take a long time, so in the end the progress bar can also stay idle for a long time, making it look like a program has stalled.

For the inpatient users out there I though I might include an indicator, which just continuously spins a simple ASCII animation, reassuring them that theres still some computing going on.
I have a problem combining it with the progress bar updates though - if I use a carriage return it displays where my progress bar should be and I'd rather have it befor the PB, something like this:

```
Busy /
0     25    50    75    100%
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
[*****************
```

The code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            int barLength = 100;
            int jobLength = 501;
            double stepSize = (double) barLength / (double) jobLength;

            String message = "Busy";
            RotatingProgressBar progressBar = new RotatingProgressBar(message);
            progressBar.start();

            System.out
                    .println("0                        25                       50                       75                       100%");
            System.out
                    .println("|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|");

            for (int i = 0; i <= jobLength; i++) {

                Thread.sleep(100);

                double progress = (stepSize * i) / barLength;
                updateProgress(progress, barLength);

            }

            progressBar.setShowProgress(false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }// END: main

    static void updateProgress(double progressPercentage, int barLength) {

        System.out.print("\r[");
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < (int) (progressPercentage * (barLength - 1)); i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for (; i < barLength - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print("]");
    }// END: updateProgress

    static class RotatingProgressBar extends Thread {

        private final String anim = "|/-\\";
        private boolean showProgress = true;
        private String message;

        public RotatingProgressBar(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {

            int i = 0;

            while (showProgress) {

                System.out.print("\r");
                System.out.print(message + anim.charAt(i++ % anim.length()));

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(10);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // do nothing
                }// END: try-catch

            }// END: while

        }// END: run

        public void setShowProgress(boolean showProgress) {
            this.showProgress = showProgress;
        }

//      public void setCarriageColumn(int column) {
//          this.column = column;
//      }
    }// END: class

}// END: class
```

Comment: " if I use a carriage return it displays where my progress bar should be and I'd rather have it before the PB ". Can't move a whole code-base to native at this point, because of one progress indicator :)

Comment: You need to use a "backspace" character to "erase" the characters that were previously printed, Java's not really well equipped to handle this

Comment: @GáborBakos I don't think I can be any clearer than that, it literally displays where my progress bar should go. If you still don't understand please run the code snippet which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MadProgrammer as in System.out.print("\b\r") ? Tried that, didn't do any difference.

Comment: Don't know about `\r`, but `\b` sounds right

Comment: @MadProgrammer \r is the carriage return, this takes it back to the beginning of the line to have that whole animation effect going on.

Comment: But shouldn't you just back up over ALL the characters you've already printed, maybe I'm missing something.  Also, this won't work in most IDE's, as their output windows are based on "consoles", just so you know.  As I read it, you need to erase something like 3 and a bit lines on each update

Comment: @fbielejec alternatively you could print out **busy...** right after the end of the bar :)) that would be good enough hehe

Comment: @nafas - That's not a bad idea actually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this, inspired by @Stefan Lindenberg and @nafas. I merged two methods into one, the busy indicator spins continuously as the last character of the progress bar, which I update with a progress:

```
class ProgressBar extends Thread {

    private static final String anim = "|/-\\";
    private boolean showProgress;
    double progressPercentage;
    private final int barLength;

    public ProgressBar(int barLength) {
        this.barLength = barLength;
        this.showProgress = true;
        this.progressPercentage = 0;
    }

    public void run() {

        int i = 0;

        while (showProgress) {

            String progress = "\r";
            int column = (int) (progressPercentage * barLength);
            for (int j = 0; j <= column; j++) {
                progress += ("*");
            }

            System.out.print(progress + anim.charAt(i++ % anim.length()));

            try {

                Thread.sleep(10);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do nothing
            }// END: try-catch

        }// END: while

    }// END: run

    public void setShowProgress(boolean showProgress) {
        this.showProgress = showProgress;
    }

    public void setProgressPercentage(double progressPercentage) {
        this.progressPercentage = progressPercentage;
    }
}// END: class
```

and this is then used like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= jobLength; i++) {

            Thread.sleep(100);

            double progress = (stepSize * i) / barLength;
            progressBar.setProgressPercentage(progress);

        }
```

Looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to delete chars that have been already printed to System.out:

```
 public void deleteChar(int times) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print((char) 8);
    }
}
```

But this (and other workarounds) are not going to work in all types of terminals/consoles. This will work in Windows cmd, powershell and most Unix terminals, but it will fail in Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: what method is that? System.out.print(*3 arguments*); ??

Comment: Sorry, was taken from a different context.